# How to make Android xml custom ui elements that are not images

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

When making a website with html and css you can simply make a box by giving a couple of div tags some attributes like color and such, what is the Android xml equivalent to this? I need to make a layout with simple elements like this example, whether it be just a rectangle or a circle, that can rescale with the screen. Is there a way to do that? Even a link to a tutorial would be greatly appreciated, i could not find anything myself.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the Android xml equivalent to this?

To the extent that there is an equivalent, you could use a [a `ShapeDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape), used in an `ImageView` or possibly as a background to something else.

Please understand that not everything that is easy in Web development will be easy in other platforms, and not everything that is difficult in Web development will be difficult in other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View` and give it a background.
If you want a rectangle, you can just assign the color you want:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

If you want to have a circle as background, or something other, you can create a drawable file using shapes:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

and assigning it to the view:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />
```

where "circle" is the name of the file with the shape

Answer (score 0):

The Fastest way to make custom buttons and any kind of background.
**Oval, Rectangle etc.**

In your case as i am getting is that you want an rectangle like we do in HTML/CSS.
**Here is an video with very much clarity, i found :**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WkJTunLf5iE

In this video he described about custom buttons but you can use it same with your required background and set it to you view like this :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />
```

That's it !!